# run sonarQube via jenkins Task 'my-task' does not exist. Please use 'list' task to see all available tasks

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I've got a server in work which has sonarQube, Gitlab and jenkins running side by side with Maven also on the box. I have also a project on this box i wish to test with sonarqube (located on this same box in /home/{user}/live/{sitename}/htdocs). I created a job in sonarqube, the only options i had where to call it something and I've no idea how this links to the actual project or where it is expecting to find the project to scan. in jenkins I added build step for sonarqube, again no option on where to find the code. i ran it anyway and to no surprise it failed asking me to use list to see all available, not being funny but where do i do this?

So I have 2 questions really:

1. where is sonarQube looking for this code, i presume symbolic links are good in this location to the actual code right?
2. where do i find and use this list command? is this in jenkins or sonarqube?

sonarqube jankins and gitlab are all accessible on our intranet with different default ports (8080, 8008 and 9000) i have the sonarqube scanner plugin on jenkins and it is using maven? Does anyone know of any good tutorials to setup this kind of scenario?

thanks

Craig

Comment: Did you read the documentation https://redirect.sonarsource.com/plugins/jenkins.html? This should help a lot. Especially since you have a Maven project, this is very simple to trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working in the end but after upgrading sonarqube we decided to use the new pipelines feature, this took a while to configure but we are now able to do code analysis on our builds, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366301/sonarqube-url-connection-refused-for-quality-gate-using-jenkins-pipeline) for details

Answer (score 1):

Configure your current Job and set below.

> `Under Build->Execute SonarQube Scanner`
>
> **Task to run :** leave it blank
>
> **Path to project properties:** Specify your sonar project properties file
>   path
>
> Before doing above changes make sure that below configurations are set
>
> `Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Sonar Servers`
>
> **Name**:Sonarqube
>
> **Server URL**: http://localhost:9000/sonarqube
>
> **Server authentication token**: Generate in SonarQube in specify here
>
> **Jenkins**->Manage Jenkins->Global Tool Configuration->SonarQube Scanner
>
> **SonarQube Scanner installations**:
>
> **Name**: SonarScanner
>
> **Install automatically**: Tick checkbox
>
> **Install from Maven Center**: Choose compatible SonarScanner version