# sonarqube url connection refused for Quality Gate using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

After a good 2 days trying to get Jenkins pipelines to work I've hit an issue in the Quality Gate section I'm unable to resolve.

Both Jenkins and SonarQube are on the same server in our network (say 192.168.0.6) Sonarqube can be accessed from this server using localhost:9000 and on my dev computer I've added sonar.ecl to the hosts file pointing to 192.168.0.6

Jenkins is accessed with 192.168.0.6:8080 on my dev box and localhost:8080 from the netwrok server.

Both servers are running and can be visitied from a web browser on my machine and via vnc on the network machine (or from the server itself (it has ubuntu 16.04 on it))

I am able to get the project into the workspace and call sonar-scanner to generate the sonarqube analysis which i can see from within sonarqube. This is great and works perfectly however the next stage on the pipeline is the call to sonarqube to get the result of the quality gate, this fails with the following java error

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:101)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:198)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:172)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:358)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:117)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:329)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:276)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:209)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:154)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:143)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.HttpClient.getHttp(HttpClient.java:37)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getCETask(WsClient.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.checkTaskCompleted(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:178)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor455.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request http://192.168.0.6:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWSj17JD0O7Ts6ZE1YHG
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:212)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:154)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:143)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.HttpClient.getHttp(HttpClient.java:37)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getCETask(WsClient.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.checkTaskCompleted(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:178)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor455.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:20)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor399.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Now in Jenkins I've got the url for sonarqube as localhost:9000 and in sonar.properties it is set as sonar.web.host=localhost and sonar.web.port=9000 so I've no idea how it is changing it to 192.168.0.6:9000?

Can anyone give me a pointer how to complete this step? Here is my pipeline (with credential details not shown)

```
node {
   def mvnHome
   stage('SCM') {
      git 'git@bitbucket.org:group/project.git'
      mvnHome = tool 'M3'
   }
   stage('SonarQube analysis') {
        def scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScanner';
        withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') { 
          sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner " +
          '-Dsonar.projectKey=jobadmin-pipeline:master ' +
          '-Dsonar.login=creds ' +
          '-Dsonar.password=***** ' +
          '-Dsonar.sources=. ' +
          '-Dsonar.exclusions=**/lib/**'
        }
    }
    stage("SonarQube Quality Gate") { 
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { 
           def qg = waitForQualityGate() 
           if (qg.status != 'OK') {
             error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Additional Information:
On the server hosting jenkins and sonar the following url's work http://localhost:9000 and http://sonar.ecl, but http://192.168.0.6:9000 doesn't.

My apache conf file is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sonar.ecl
    ServerAdmin sonar@somewhere.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/sonar_access.log
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sonar_error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I still haven't determined why java is looking at http://192.168.0.6:9000 is there another location I've overlooked, even grep for 192.168.0.6 hasn't helped yet.

In jenkins the url seems to change as the scanner is finishing

```
13:03:54.840 DEBUG: POST 200 http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=jobadmin-pipeline:master | time=244ms
13:03:54.842 INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 246ms
13:03:54.842 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://192.168.0.6:9000/dashboard/index/jobadmin-pipeline:master
13:03:54.842 INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
13:03:54.842 INFO: More about the report processing at http://192.168.0.6:9000/api/ce/task?id=AWSoIB5vjatNRUhjlocT
```

I've since reconfigured the url in jenkins to use sonar.ecl but again it hits the end of the Analysis and shows the same incorrect url (http://192.168.0.6:9000/dashboard/index/jobadmin-pipeline:master - ie not sonar.ecl) and this is used in quality gate and breaks.

So as i see it there are 2 solutions 1/ we find where this ip address is coming from or 2 we allow this ip in apache.

I'm not sure how to do either, I tried the latter for at least 6 hours yesterday and was unable to have the url of 192.168.0.6:9000 to work on SonarQube yet sonar.ecl works (via hosts on the server)

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the "Execute Analysis" rights for the user you use?

Comment: That would make sense, I'll have a look in morning when at desk

Comment: Wild guess: your Server base URL (set in global admin) is http://192.168.0.6:9000

Comment: @Jeroen the user has Execute analysis enabled, my issue is when the scanner has completed, the data is available in SonarQube dashboard. The pipeline is failing when jenkins tries to connect to the sonar server via a web interface polling for the quality gate result.

Comment: @G. Ann I have amended my initial post with latest findings and changes

Comment: @CraigStanfield is your "Server base URL" set to the unexpected address?

Comment: @G. Ann No sorry it was initially set as http://localhost:9000 and it changed to http://192.168.0.6:9000 after the analysis but before it polls the quality gate so i changed it to http://sonar.ecl but this also worked but changed to http://192.168.0.6:9000 at the same point. So the sonar alalysis is happening but when i use -X in the sonar-scanner call then it shows the url being correct but mysteriously changes just before the status gate is called.

Comment: @CraigStanfield in your SonarQube instance in Global Administration > General > Server base URL, what is the value?

Comment: Thanks @G. Ann It was indeed the Server base URL set in SonarQube, I'd been assuming you had meant in Jenkins which was correct. I have now successfully completed my first pipeline with code analysis using SonarQube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As G. Ann had suggested this was down to an incorrect url setting in SonarQube (Administration > General > Server base URL) setting this to http://localhost:9000 fixed my issue completely. Huge upvote for having this one from the start.